# How do I calculate the time intervals (PHP)?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have work hours, for example, from 9:00 to 18:00

I have a break time, for example, from 13:00 to 14:00

I have a busy time, for example, from 15:00 to 18:00

How in PHP is it most efficient to calculate and display the client free time (9:00 to 13:00 and 14:00 to 15:00)?

Perhaps the best solution would be to translate time into unixtime, or use associative arrays, or start time + duration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I keep the time in minutes since 00:00 in the same date. Using DateTime might be problematic since it takes the day into consideration.

```
Time_in_minutes = Hour*60+minute.
```

Here is an (basic) algorithm that should do what you need. You have to refine it, as it assumes there are no overlapping items in the schedule:

```
<?php
class Interval {
    // TODO: use getter/setters instead of public
    public $from; // in minutes, included
    public $to;   // in minutes, excluded

    public function __construct($from, $to) {
        $this->from = $from;
        $this->to = $to;
    }
}

$intervals = array(new Interval(8*60, 18*60));

$schedule = array(
    new Interval(13*60, 14*60),
    new Interval(15*60, 18*60)
    );

foreach( $schedule as $item ) {
    foreach($intervals as $interval) {
        // TODO: the algorithm assumes there are no overlapping items in the schedule
        if ($interval->from <= $item->from && $interval->to >= $item->to) {
            if ($interval->from == $item->from) {
                $interval->from = $item->to;
            } else if ($interval->to == $item->to) {
                $interval->to = $item->from;
            } else {
                $intervals[] = new Interval($item->to, $interval->to);
                $interval->to = $item->from;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

foreach($intervals as $interval)
    echo sprintf("%02d:%02d-%02d:%02d\n", $interval->from / 60, $interval->from % 60,$interval->to / 60, $interval->to % 60);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP DateTime class.  It provides many ways to do arithmetic about time intervals.  Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php